# Save a .csv file with a semicolon instead of a comma in VBS

Tags: excel, csv, vbscript, export-to-csv

I need to convert a list of excel files into semicolon csv file through a vbs file because a program I use only imports vbs files with semicolon as separator, I programmed this small file in vbs, but it manages to export it as csv with the comma, not semicolon.

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
objStartFolder = "C:\Users\loren\Desktop\eFolder" 'folder where my Excel files are saved

Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(objStartFolder)
Set colFiles = objFolder.Files
For Each objFile in colFiles
    csv_format = 6
    
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    src_file = objStartFolder & "\" & objFile.Name 'Input files
    dest_file = objStartFolder & "\OUTPUT\" & objFile.Name & ".csv" 'Output files
    
    Dim oExcel
    Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    
    Dim oBook
    Set oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(src_file)
    
    oBook.SaveAs dest_file, csv_format
    
    oBook.Close False
    oExcel.Quit
Next
```

Comment: If your data contains any commas, be sure to   replace these three characters `","` with these three characters `";"` instead of just targeting the comma only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by saving the file with Local argument's parameter set to True. Thanks to the response from @VBasic2008

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
objStartFolder = "C:\Users\loren\Desktop\eFolder"

Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(objStartFolder)
Set colFiles = objFolder.Files
For Each objFile in colFiles
    csv_format = 6
    
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    src_file = objStartFolder & "\" & objFile.Name
    dest_file = objStartFolder & "\OUTPUT\" & objFile.Name & ".csv"
    
    Dim oExcel
    Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    
    Dim oBook
    Set oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(src_file)
    
    oBook.SaveAs dest_file, csv_format, , , , , , , , , , True
    
    oBook.Close False
    oExcel.Quit
    
Next
```

Comment: Do you really need to open the files in Excel instead of just replacing the commas via the FileSystemObject directly?

Comment: If you Excel list separator is a semicolon (`;`) you could consider saving the file with `Local` argument's parameter set to `True`: `Local:=True` i.e. `oBook.SaveAs Filename:=dest_file, FileFormat:=csv_format, Local:=True` i.e. `oBook.SaveAs dest_file, csv_format, , , , , , , , , , True` ([Workbook.SaveAs method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.saveas)).